# How to create an GKE HTTP(S) Load Balancer without domain or hostname

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, load-balancing, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I have a service called controller running on a GKE cluster.

```
controller   NodePort    10.27.XX.XX    <none>        80:32544/TCP                 2d
```

I have exposed this service with an Ingress. The Ingress file:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: voip
  name: basic
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: controller
    servicePort: 80
```

After running `kubectl -n voip get ingress`. I see:

```
NAME      HOSTS     ADDRESS       PORTS     AGE
basic     *         34.95.XX.XX   80        4h
```

I am running a React App that is calling this ip address as the server the ingress is pointing to is a RESTful API to gran information from the cluster. However, because the React app is running over HTTP(S) The browser will not allow the app the make calls to http://34.95.XX.XX. However, the ingress is not set up to take HTTP(S) traffic. I can not seem to figure out how to set up HTTP(S) traffic to this cluster without a domain name. I want to create a cluster per customer and each cluster will have its own controller service to communicate with the Front-end app. So how do I create a  HTTP(S) Load Balancer on GKE without a domain name ?

Comment: there's shouldn't be any issues with your GKE ingress . Did you wait enough time before testing your ingress, because it may take up to 5 minutes to set up firewall rules. Can you also share you application deployment so I could try to reproduce?

Comment: You can follow this tutorial

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/nginx-ingress-gke

Comment: My question is once the Ingress is running, how do I get it to be able to handle HTTPS traffic? because I need a self signed Cert or Third party cert for every HTTPS Ingress

Comment: nginx ingress requires a domain by default. Why don't you buy a wildcard certificate with a domain, connect the domain to Cloud DNS. Use terraform to create GKE cluster with Cloud DNS record subdomain, when you are deploying a new customer.

Comment: @Miro that would be awesome, can you give me a link of some sort of link to document or tutorial?

Comment: Did I miss mentioning of the nginx ingress somewhere in the post?  With your implementation of the ingress, GCP will provide you a loadbalancer for your cluster. And where this statement **the ingress is not set up to take HTTP(S) traffic** comes from?